# Using std::string Datatype in std::vector's Constructor

Tags: c++, stl, rapidxml

This isn't so much a specific question about RapidXML convention as it is a question about using a std::vector's constructor.

In all examples that I have found of others using RapidXML, everyone always reads data into a vector of `char`'s using the `std::vector`'s constructor like so:

```
vector<char> buffer((istreambuf_iterator<char>(theFile)), istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

There must be a reason for this because when I try to change it to a vector of `std::string`'s I get a screen full of errors with this being the first error:

```
error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘std::istreambuf_iterator<std::basic_string<char> >::streambuf_type* {aka std::basic_streambuf<std::basic_string<char>, std::char_traits<std::basic_string<char> > >*}’
```

Is there a way to use std::string and if not why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you trying to do?

Do you want the contents of the file in a single string? If so, then

```
string buffer((istreambuf_iterator<char>(theFile)), istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

should do it.

On the other hand, if you want a vector of strings, with each string containing a single line from the file, you'll have to write a loop like this (untested code):

```
vector <string> lines;
for (string aLine; std::getline(theFile, aLine) ; )
    lines.push_back(aLine);
```

Comment: Oh, I see! `istreambuf_iterator()` reads character-by-character and has to be of type `char`. I thought that if I read items in as `std:string`'s I would be able to compare them easier. For example `if(column_node->value().compare("Coil and Switch resistance") == 0)`.

Comment: Shorter: `string buffer(istreambuf_iterator<char>(theFile), {});`